# ggplot can't find custom key_glyph function when not defined in global environment

Tags: r, ggplot2

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)

set.seed(123)

y <- rnorm(100)

df <- tibble(y) %>% 
  mutate(os = factor(rep_len(1:5, 100)),
         date = seq(from = ymd('2013-01-01'), by = 1, length.out = 100))

foo <- function() {

  draw_key_cust <- function(data, params, size) {
    if (data$colour %in% c("red", "blue"))
      draw_key_vpath(data, params, size)
    else
      draw_key_path(data, params, size)
  }
  
  ggplot(df, aes(x = date, y = y, colour = os)) +
    geom_line() +
    geom_vline(
      aes(xintercept = min(date), linetype = 'os 1'), 
      colour = 'red', key_glyph = "cust") +
    geom_vline(
      aes(xintercept = median(date), linetype = 'os 2'), 
      colour = 'black', key_glyph = "cust") +
    geom_hline(
      aes(yintercept = 1, linetype = "dashed"), 
      colour = "blue", key_glyph = "cust"
    ) +
    geom_hline(
      aes(yintercept = -1, linetype = "dashed 2"), 
      colour = "purple", key_glyph = "cust"
    ) +
    
    scale_linetype_manual(
      name = 'lines',
      values = c(2, 2, 1, 1),
      guide = guide_legend(override.aes = list(colour = c('red', 'black', 'blue', "purple"))))

}

foo()
```

[image]

because `draw_key_cust` is defined inside of `foo`, it can't find it. If I define it inside of the global environment, then it will work.

How to make it work without having to define the function in the global environment?

Comment: Is there a reaon for defining one function inside another?  The way you have it, calling foo() is the same as calling draw_key_cust().

Comment: If there is a reason, could you not define the `draw_key_cust()` function and then define `foo()` to call `draw_key_cust()`, i.e. do it in two steps?